# Duplicate error when updating cross-reference item

Tags: acumatica

When updating cross-reference items in Inventory, we get a duplicate key error. Looking into it, we discovered that when updating, the query does not filter by InventoryID only by SubItemID, AlternateID,AlternateType and BaccountID. This causes a problem when updating or deleting. Deleting a record will actually delete all items having the same subitemid, alternateid,alternatetype and baccountid but different InventoryID. Has this happened to anyone else? We are using version 5.1

Comment: Could you share a code sample which shows this problem? And have you checked whether it happens without any customization installed?

Comment: We received confirmation from Acumatica that the duplicate error is caused by how we use the XRef items. When updating or deleting they are not filtered by inventoryID by design. We decided to use custom objects to achieve what we need instead.

Comment: What was the case number? Curious to read (I work for Acumatica)

Comment: Never mind, I found it. Support opened a bug report.